# How to create an ASP.NET RSS feed

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, webforms, rss

How do I create an RSS feed in ASP.NET? Is there anything built in to support it?  If not, what third-party tools are available?

I'm thinking Webforms, not MVC, though I suppose since this isn't a traditional page the difference may be minimal.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416175/creating-an-rss-feed-in-asp-net-3-5 (not voting to close as this one is older and has more answers, although all the answers here are more or less just links, and it has fewer views than the potential target).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For built-in, there's nothing stopping you from using XmlDocument or XDocument (3.5) to build up the required XML for RSS. It's more work than it's worth though.

I use the [Argotic Syndication Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic) and serve the feeds through Generic Handlers (.ashx) with the content type set to text/xml.

The [RSSToolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit) is also nice. It comes with an RSSDataSource control if you're into that sort of thing. It also includes a control that will automatically insert the meta tag required for feed autodiscovery in browsers. I found the build provider for creating feeds to be a little kludgey however.

Answer (score 11):

The .NET Framework 3.5 has added a SyndicationFeed Class which allows you to create and/or consume feeds in Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0 formats.

[SyndicationFeeds Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an RSS framework created by a Microsoft developer: [ASP.NET RSS Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit)

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the libraries available for generating the actual RSS. For example: http://www.rssdotnet.com/

If you check the code examples page at the bottom:
http://www.rssdotnet.com/documents/code_examples.html
you will find the code for clearing the content type in an ASP.net Page and outputting the RSS.

Something along the lines of (not tested, not compiled, just typed):

```
public void PageLoad()
{

// create channel
RssChannel _soChannel = new RssChannel();

// create item
RssItem _soItem = new RssItem();
_soItem.Title = "Answer";
_soItem.Description = "Example";
_soItem.PubDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

// add to channel
_soChannel.Items.Add(_soItem.);

// set channel props
_soChannel.Title = "Stack Overflow";
_soChannel.Description = "Great site.. jada jada jada";
_soChannel.LastBuildDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

// change type and send to output
RssFeed _f = new RssFeed();
_f.Channels.Add(channel);
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
_f.Write(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Argotic. It is a really cool framework.

http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic

Answer (score -1):

Create an HTTP Handler to create a RSS feed