# Make an ASP.NET Web service output an RSS Feed

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rss

I have been writing some Web services to be used by a few different client apps and i was trying to write a web service method that simply outputs an RSS XML Feed.

I can create the XML using an XmlTextWriter Object

Then i have tryed outputing to the Response (like i have done in the past when its an aspx page) but this only works it the return type is void (and still doesnt seem to output properly)

Then i tryed making the return type a string and using a StringWriter to output the xml from the XmlTextWriter but the output is then wrapped in a  tag.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously create the interfaces and rest of the WCF service as normal.

Mark the class with the following attribute

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

And then this function

```
public Stream GetRSS()
{
 string output;
 //output = some_text;
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
 WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
 return ms;
}
```

Comment: im getting an Object reference error doing with the 
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
any ideas?

Comment: If you still get the error, im not sure. Maybe its the way you are starting the service. This is from a working project of mine.

Comment: ok, i dont think im using a WCF web service... how do i create 1 of them?

Comment: ah. u misread the question. my answer is for a wcf service not an asmx

Comment: oh ok, what kind of advantages would i get from using a MCF service instead of an amsx? (this early in the development i can still change over easily)

Comment: WCF is the new technology for services in .net, so you would get experience in the latest technology.  WCF is also more standards compliant, and can be used with multiple protocols, not just HTTP

Comment: Not only is WCF "new", ASMX is old. It has little life left in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code for this, but it's more than will fit well in an SO post (about 1000 lines).  It's really not that hard; the schema is simple enough you can do it yourself, but you don't have to: there are several components you can just plug in to create the xml for you.

You should see this question:
[ASP.Net RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287/asp-net-rss-feed)

Comment: I already have created the RSS XML now im looking to get the webservice call to output it directly...

Answer (score 0):

If you must use ASMX, then you can return an XmlDocument. Build the feed XML however you like, but then return the XmlDocument from your web method.